# Regarding querying Java Map with values as array of string.

Tags: java, arrays, string, collections, dictionary

I have map of string and array of strings as:

```
private static Map cacheTimeStamp = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
```

now how do i get value of this Map, i want to return array of String[] back to the calling function, tried using `cacheTimeStamp.get("stringKey")` but it returns object and i want to get array of strings out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your map like this:

```
private static Map<String, String[]> cacheTimeStamp = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
```

Problem is that you are defining an open map without specifying map's key and value object types. Which is essentially a key of type `java.lang.Object` and a value of type `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the generics.

```
Map<String, String[]> cacheTimeStamp = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
```

It actually **did** return an array of Strings, but strictly you don't know when you don't include the generics in the definition. That's why the IDE tells you it will be an Object. Make sure you are beware of the fact that an array **is** an Object.

Answer (score 0):

You actually get an `String[]`.

I see two options:

1. Cast the return value to an String[]:

   String[] myEntry = (String[]) cacheTimeStamp.get("stringKey");
2. (My preference) Add type arguments to the map:

   private static Map cacheTimeStamp = new HashMap();
   // ...
   String[] myEntry = cacheTimeStamp.get("stringKey");